# Bounds on chromatic number in terms of chromatic numbers of subgraphs.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph G of the form $G = G1 \cup G2$, and graphs G1 and G2 are defined by $V(G1) = V(G2)$. How can we describe the dynamics of the chromatic number of G in relation to the chromatic numbers of G1 and G2? My prof mentioned in class that it should be the case that $\chi (G) \leq \chi (G1)\times \chi (G2)$ and left it as an exercise to figure out why, but I've been struggling to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: **Hint:** If $G_1$ is colored with colors $A,B,C$ and $G_2$ with colors $X,Y$, you can color $G_1\cup\G_2$ with colors $AX,AY,BX,BY,CX,CY$.